# Query to fetch superset if subset combination returns null result?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

```
TABLE : **PROFILE**
RUN_ID| Type | code | gender | vacId

1     | A    | biz  | M      | 110
2     | A    | pro  | M      | 113
3     | A    | tot  | F      | 114
```

Required to return the vacId, based on the input if I input, if code+type combination is not present then return only vacId which equals to given type

1. TYPE=A AND CODE=BIZ AND GENDER=M , then it should return 110
2. TYPE=A AND CODE=SYS then should return 110 & 113 , 114 there is no A+SYS combination so returned superset A's data

How can I write a query for this which should work in pgsql and oracle for now.

Is there a way that I can achieve this using **COALESCE**

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional `where` clause, e.g. (`$` used for parameters):

```
select p.*
from profile p
where case
    when exists (
        select 1
        from profile
        where type = $type and code = $code and gender = $gender
        )
    then type = $type and code = $code and gender = $gender
    else type = $type
    end;
```

Update.

An alternative solution could be to get results in a single json object, what will enable you to use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(
    (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(p))
    from profile p
    where type = $type and code = $code and gender = $gender),
    (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(p))
    from profile p
    where type = $type)
);
```

Comment: Is this will hit database more than once ? any performance issue in this query ? Can add more than one case here ?

Comment: The subquery involves an additional scan, but it is cheaper than the main one, especially when appropriate index(es) is/are in use. You can use multiple subqueries in the `case` statement, just add `when ... then ...` before `else`.

Comment: Just an additional query. To reduce the performance risk, Will it be better to return all json data and on View(front end) it will filter ?

Comment: This largely depends on actual data returned by your queries. Basically, you should reduce the amount of data transferred from the server. Using a suitable index the solution with a conditional `WHERE` clause may be quite efficient and better than filtering the data on client side.

Comment: Alternate Solution- where to_jsonb() function is defined ?

Comment: [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)